# iOS back button turns totally black

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

During the test process of my app, only 2 people said their back button turns totally black, showed in the following image:
[image]

I've searched the Internet but failed to find a similar problem.
Can someone tell me why does this happen?

Edit: Well actually my code that has sth to deal with the tint color is only this single one:
`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor BBTAppGlobalBlue]];` In `AppDelegate.m`
In which `BBTAppGlobalBlue` is a custom color, which should be a kind of blue.

Comment: Can you post code of how your creating your back button? It looks like you're using a custom one

Comment: is tintColor black?

Comment: If you post a problem without code it is literally no help to anyone.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question.

Comment: where is your answer??? I think it's question!

Comment: Ahhhh..careless mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I am not sure for this ans.Try once changing button shape.